# Move a method between classes using RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubymine, automated-refactoring

How do (can I?) I move a method from one class to another using RubyMine?

I tried right-clicking on the method name, selecting `Refactor`, and `Move ...`, but that gives me `Move file path/to/file.rb To directory:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move method refactoring is not supported yet, please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-2987).